# Error in random intercept and random slope model

Tags: r, lmer

I am using the `lme4` package in R and trying to fit in a random slope and random intercept model.
I would be really helpful if anyone can help me understanding this error when I run a random slope and random intercept model and what to do regarding this error:

```
mdl17<-lmer(yld.res ~ brk + (1+brk|state),data=data1,REML="FALSE")
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
   Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 1.84098 (tol = 0.002, component 3)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
   Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: First: you should state, if true, that this is from the package `lme4` . Next: Convergence failure happens when your data set isn't stable, or doesn't have a unique solution (underdefined, e.g.).   Fitting algorithms aren't magic.

Comment: Yes I am using the lme4 package. So that means there is nothing I can do regarding this? I had tried this by rescaling the data but still it does not work

Comment: PS. You probably want `REML=FALSE`, not `REML="FALSE"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @CarlWitthoft stated the warning informs you about a convergence failure of your model. It can be either under- or overdefined. You should also check if the model you’re trying to fit makes sense at all. Furthermore, you should definitely install the most current version of the `lme4` package by running `update.packages("lme4")` or (if you want to update all packages) `update.packages()`. The current `lme4` packages contains its own page about convergence warnings. After you have loaded it via `library(lme4)` you can access that man page by issuing `?convergence`. There you will find additional info about your warning message. (Note, that future version may not necessarily contain this page.) As an additional measure, you can search how to use a different optimizer. The new version of `lme4` e.g. imports `nloptr` which can be used.

You should also check `lme4`’s Github page: https://github.com/lme4/lme4/ in cases were you encounter warning or error messages that you find worrying. For your specific case there is some information that might be relevant:

> "Recent versions of `lme4 (e.g. 1.1-6)` give false convergence warnings. There is a summary post on r-sig-mixed-models. If you get warnings about `max|grad|` but the model passes this test:

```
dd <- fit@optinfo$derivs
with(dd,max(abs(solve(Hessian,gradient)))<2e-3)
```

> then you are seeing a false-positive warning, and the problem will disappear in future versions `(1.1-7 and up)`."[<sup>[1]</sup>](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/)

Should the `Github` page contain relevant information (e.g. that the warning or error is specific to the current version on `CRAN`) you should consider installing `lme4`’s current master from `Github` and check whether the problem disappears when you use it:

(1) First install `devtools`: `install.packages("devtools")` and attach it `library(devtools)` to your namespace.

(2) Then use: `install_github("lme4/lme4", dependencies = TRUE)` to install the latest master of the `lme4` package from Github. (Should you encounter an error indicating that building the vignettes failed despite `dependencies = TRUE` you should pass `build_vignettes = FALSE` to your call of `install_github()`.)

---

Here’s the link to the summary about convergence warnings: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.lme4.devel/11893 (retrieved 2014-07-16T10:04+02:00)

Comment: Actually, version 1.1-7 is on CRAN now, so installation from Github shouldn't be necessary.  (Unfortunately this also increases the chance that the OP is already using the latest version/has a real convergence problem ...)

Comment: What does "dd <- fit@optinfo$derivs
with(dd,max(abs(solve(Hessian,gradient)))<2e-3)" tell me? I get "FALSE". Is that good or bad?